# Unity3D - Image Slider only visible in specific area

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I am trying to build an image slider for my app.
Unfortunately all the images are shown and not only the four images between the two arrows

[image]

In picture 2 you can see my hierarchy and in picture 3 you can see my settings for the **sldImage** `GameObject`

**picture 2**

[image]

**picture 3**
[image]

what do I have to do, that the images slide in from the right and disappear left?
unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for that so far.

**EDIT:**

There is no `ScrollView` in my components.

[image]

and if I add a `Mask` it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `Mask`.

If you add a `ScrollView` to your UI instead of a basic `ScrollRect`, you get a Mask for free.

Add it using the right-click menu in the Hierarchy Window, by choosing **UI**->**ScrollView**

Comment: thanks for the help, see my edit. unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: See my edit on how to add a ScrollView to your hierarchy.

Comment: THANK YOU .. such an easy solution .. THANK YOU